# Angular: "use strict" IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, use-strict

I ran into a problem in the browser IE11. The project is in Angular 2/4.

`Error: Multiple definitions of a property not allowed in strict mode.
In file main.bundle.js`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, It is because I tried to use some code like a `case` on `ng-class` attribute.

To solved I just change this

```
<div class="imgComment" ng-class="[{'.jpg':'imgJpg',
                     '.csv':'imgCsv',
                     '.xls':'imgXls',
                     '.xlsx':'imgXlsx',
                     '.doc':'imgDoc',
                     '.docx':'imgDocx',
                     '.msg':'imgMsg',
                     '.png':'imgPng',
                     '.pdf':'imgPdf',
                     '.jpg':'imgJpg',
                     '.jpeg':'imgJpeg',
                     '.zip':'imgZip',
                     '.rar':'imgRar',
                     '.txt':'imgTxt'}['{{f.fileExtension}}']]"
                     title="{{f.originalFileName}}" ng-click="showImage(f.sharePointPath)">
                    </div>
```

for this

```
<div class="imgComment {{f.style}}" title="{{f.originalFileName}}" ng-click="showImage(f.sharePointPath)"></div>
```

and send the class in f.Style attribute

I don't know if the problem was because I put 2 '.jpg' options in the case of the `ng-class`, I just change the code and works.